# How to create a manipulator that will put to sleep or type "pause" in the console?

Tags: c++, manipulators

I'm having trouble creating the pause manipulator for the code below.
"m" is an object that prints the given numbers in morsea code. This works for me, but I don't know how to make a manipulator for it.  Can you help me with this problem?

```
long x = 0x2A6B5B5A;
double y = 8.23786789;
m<< x << pause << y ;
```

Comment: what is `<< pause <<` supposed to do?

Comment: pause should display "pause" in the console or use Sleep from windows.h

Comment: to display "pause" you would writte `m << x << "pause" << y;`

Comment: Putting [the thread] to sleep, and outputting "pause", are two completely different things. Presumably you meant to execute the "pause" Windows command but got confused about how terminals work?

Comment: Take a look at sleep. It may provide what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It is not quite clear what your code is supposed to do. However, all you need is this:

```
struct pause_t {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const pause_t& p) {
     // put code here
     return out;
};
```

Put the code that does whatever you like to happen in place of `//put code here`, then use it like this:

```
pause_t pause;
std::cout << 42 << pause << 42;
```

If `m` in your example is not a `std::ostream` then you just need to adjust above overload for `<<` accordingly.

*PS*: Strictly speaking the above is not an io manipulator. io manipulators are typically implemented as functions that take the `ostream` as parameter and `std::ostream` has an overload of `<<` for such functions. However, that distinction is probably not important in your case.

Comment: Note that if this ends up being implemented with a `system("pause")` or `std::this_thread_sleep` (as seems to be the intention), you'll probably want to throw a `flush` in there somewhere too

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I guess you mean `std::this_thread::sleep`, not `std::this_thread_sleep`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Whatever it is

Comment: @DiegoAbreu if you want to share code to clarify your question, you should do so in the question. You can edit it via [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64836322/edit)

Comment: I tried to overload like this.
`friend MorseCode operator<< (const MorseCode& m, const pause_t& p){
Sleep(2000);
    return MorseCode();
}`
And use something like that
`m << 42 << pause << 42;`
But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DiegoAbreu and? `return morse();` looks wrong.

Comment: @DiegoAbreu comments are not for answering questions. Your question should have included a [mcve] of your code then I could have included a complete answer in my answer. What I did is trying to answer your question as it stands. If you have a follow-up quesiton, please ask another question

Comment: @idclev463035818 I changed the content of the question and added some code. I hope it will help.

Comment: @DiegoAbreu no. Changing the question after you got answers is not helping. Also copying stuff from my answer into your question is a bit odd. My answer is not answering your question anymore. There are several ways to resolve this situation. I decided to roll back your edit to the original question and suggest you to ask a new question.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry for the confusion caused by a poorly asked question and trying to improve it.

Comment: @DiegoAbreu no worries, just ask a new quesiton, and please add your code